# support for theory of lists

Tags: z3

I am curious if Z3 has a built-in list sort? From the C API it seems like it does, but I am interested in inputting in SMTLIB / SMTLIB-2 format rather than using the C API, so I would like to know if Z3 provides any such support. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Z3 has a built-in list sort. Quote from [Z3 guide, section Recursive datatypes](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide):

> The List recursive datatype is builtin in Z3. The empty list is nil,
>   and the constructor insert is used to build new lists. The accessors
>   head and tail are defined as usual.

Here is a demonstrative example from that section: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/qXj9.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Is there documentation about what list functions are provided (besides head, tail, insert)? For instance accessing ith element of a list?